# How to xor predicates?

Tags: java, predicate

I need a method where I need to **xor** Predicates which I will recieve as method params. I have a somewhat working but cumbersome solution for two predicates. To give a simple, minimal and reproducible example:

```
Predicate<String> pred1  = s -> s.contains("foo");
Predicate<String> pred2  = s -> s.contains("bar");
    
String toTest = "foobar";
```

The logical **OR** will return `true` for given predicates and the test string:

```
boolean oneOnly   = pred1.or(pred2).test(toTest);
```

but for my use case it should return false since both substrings are included. It should only return true if and only if one condition is met.

For two prdeicates I have this

```
static boolean xor(Predicate<String> pred1, Predicate<String> pred2, String toTest){
    return pred1.and(pred2.negate()).or(pred2.and(pred1.negate())).test(toTest);
}
```

Is there a simple but a convinient way to xor predicates?

Comment: `return pred1.test(toTest) ^ pred2.test(toTest);`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I didn't think of something so obvious and thought rather too complicated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In followup to @xdhmoore's answer, that's overkill and can be done much simpler:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> xor(Predicate<T> pred1, Predicate<T> pred2) {
    return t -> pred1.test(t) ^ pred2.test(t);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, looking at your answer, I must have killed something to get so far afield. Good call!

Comment: This is definitely a better and an enrichment for my code, when I can chain predicates . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

Below are some examples of why you'd want to return a Predicate instead of a boolean, but @rzwitserloot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67258443/356887) does it nicely and more succinctly.

---

To play the Devil's advocate: it's less pretty, but one advantage for the way you already have it is you are slightly more in line with the Predicate idioms. A little tweaking gets you:

### Return a Predicate

```
static <T> Predicate<T> xor(Predicate<T> pred1, Predicate<T> pred2){
    return pred1.and(pred2.negate())
       .or(pred2.and(pred1.negate()));
}

// Which means you can do this, which is probably more conducive to combining your
// new xor function with other predicates:
xor((Integer a) -> a > 1, (Integer b) -> b < 10).test(0));

// For example, because you return a Predicate:
xor((Integer a) -> a > 1, (Integer b) -> b < 10).negate().test(0));
```

### Return a boolean

```
static <T> boolean xor(Predicate<T> pred1, Predicate<T> pred2, T toTest) {
    return pred1.test(toTest) ^ pred2.test(toTest);
}

// In contrast, if your xor function returns a boolean, you get this, which is 
// similar, but is less conducive to using all the Predicate methods:
xor((Integer a) -> a > 1, (Integer b) -> b < 10, 14);

// To be honest, this seems more readable to me than the negate() function in the
// example above, but perhaps there are scenarios where the above is preferred...
!xor((Integer a) -> a > 1, (Integer b) -> b < 10, 14)
```

Not a big deal, but your question made me curious...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the two approaches, the examples and the discription. I didn't think about chaining the predicates but will definetly improve my code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce your xor'ed predicates to a single predicate with stream.reduce and then return the outcome.

like so:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MultiXor{

    public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println(xor("monkey", p -> p.equals("monkey"), p -> p.equals("dork"), p -> p.equalsIgnoreCase("Monkey")) );
            System.out.println(true ^ false ^ true);
            System.out.println(xor("monkey", p -> p.equals("monkey"), p -> p.equals("dork")) );
            System.out.println(true ^ false);

    }

    public static <T> boolean xor(final T param, Predicate<T>... predicates){
            return Arrays.stream(predicates).reduce( p -> false, (previous, p) -> r -> previous.test(param) ^ (p.test(param))).test(param);
    }
```

}